# Why is salt sometimes ingredient of otherwise sweet cookies?

Tags: baking, salt, cookies

In some recipes for muffins, biscuits or cakes I find small amounts of salt as an ingredient ([Chocolate cake](http://www.browneyedbaker.com/2012/04/26/chocolate-fudge-brownies-with-chocolate-buttercream-frosting/), [Banana muffin](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/banana-crumb-muffins/detail.aspx)). Why? What can a pinch of salt add to the bowl of chocolate?

Comment: Very closely related: [Why is it important to add salt during cooking?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/19411) and [Should you add some salt to flour when baking?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2860)

Comment: The key difference here is why salt is being added to Sweet things such as cookies.

Comment: @MandoMando The proposed duplicate is asking about sweet things (cakes, muffins, puddings), though it does for some reason say the salt is added to the flour, instead of the recipe as a whole. But in any case, the answer isn't any different for cookies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question.  the salt is not there for the taste of salt. A pinch of salt helps with the ionization process so your taste buds can pick up the tsate of the chocolate, ice cream, etc, better.

I think this was discussed in an episode of Alton Brown's Good Eats as well.

Comment: Not just an episode, he did a full hour long special on salt.

Answer (score 2):

It enhances the flavour of the chocolate, vinegar is used in a similar way when added to cream sauces and mousses. We use vinegar to bring out the flavour of aubergine in our mushroom and aubergine sauce. Worth a try! :)