# Does salt do anything more for baked products than just add flavor?

Tags: baking, salt

From a chemical scientific stand point... What roles does salt play in food besides the usual afterthought of sprinkling some on top of your food item to increase/enhance the flavor.  I know this is vague so lets just say bread.  Why all these years have chefs/food scientist bothered adding salt to almost every bread recipe?

Does salt control moisture?  Does salt control yeast activity? does salt control sugar regulation between the yeast through osmosis?

(Side not: Sorry if some of this is worded oddly.  There thoughts straight off the brain.)

Comment: Agreed: hobodave's answer to the linked question addresses yeast specifically.  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/2864/25059

Comment: Went ahead and marked as duplicate. @Chef_Code, if there's something different you were trying to ask here, feel free to edit your question and flag for reopening!

Comment: What actions if any do I take if a question is found to be a duplicate? I don't want to protest it, I agree that this is a duplicate and that the predecessor question, answers my question. @Jefromi

Comment: @Chef_Code Nothing, it's already marked as a duplicate. I just commented in case it wasn't really and you wanted to fix it!